# How can I open an iPhone's SIM card slot without the included pin?

Tags: substitute-tool, technology

When purchased, iPhones come with this pin that you use to open the slot on the side to insert your SIM card. Now it's way beyond me how it's happened but out of the 3 iPhones I have I only have the original box for one of them and the pin is missing.

So how can I open up the SIM card slot of an iPhone without the pin. I tried a toothpick but it's too fat to fit into the hole.

Answer (score 17):

I have successfully opened an iPhone card slot using a paper clip.

Just straighten a standard sized paper clip and poke the end in the hole.  It is a tight fit but it works.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can try the tip of a small safety pin to open it.

That's always worked for me, though you may want to be careful about poking yourself.

Comment: Safety pin is sharp at an end. Be safe no to poke yourself and poke the internals of the hole to eject the sim tray.

Comment: If I'm not wrong inside the hole is a small plastic "seesaw" (I'm not a physicist so I'm not really too sure what the technical term is) that, when pressed down, pushes the SIM slot out from its location. I doubt there are any internals to poke, but do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, there is a lever to push which will eject the tray.

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't have a paper clip: 
I've used a [mechanical pencil](https://www.google.com/search?q=mechanical+pencil) once, with success.

Be careful it doesn't break!

Comment: Although it should be noted that some mechanical pencils use leads up to several mm in diameter (which certainly won't work) - what diameter do you suggest? 0.5mm?

Answer (score 0):

I have whittled a wooden pin from a piece of wood once - it was strong enough to push out the SIM holder, but I wouldn't want to use that repeatedly, as I was worried it would break inside the ejection slot.

Answer (score 0):

As said a paperclip or a safety pin is your best bet. I used them occasinally. Even if you have colorful paper clips (a bit thicker than normal) you can strip the plastic with scissors.
When I had an iPhone, I used to use my glasses since they were thin enough.

Comment: Which part of your glasses did you use? Or do you mean that you whittled down a plastic portion of your glasses?

Comment: @Lawrence I had titanium frame, hence the sides of the frame was as thin as a paperclip, and fit in the pin slot.

Comment: I see. Thanks for mentioning that. Even for titanium frames, most have a thicker sheathe around the tips, perhaps to avoid people stabbing themselves accidentally. It might help for you to post a picture.

Comment: @Lawrence I don't have the glasses anymore because I got Lasik but here is the link to the image of it I found on Google. https://goo.gl/images/mvDymT     I hope it helps, even though I don't see the point. It was very useful when I had them to take the sim tray off. Now I carry the pin in my backpack or ask for someone's earring to take it off.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the back of earrings to open SIM card slots as well as press the small reset holes in some technical devices. They mostly have the right size to fit into the hole and the probability that I have one with me all the time is high. You have to be carefull not to bend them though.

Answer (score -2):

I have actually was able to open the sim card slot using a *toothpick*  however any object that is small enough to fit in the tiny hole will do just be careful with the amount of pressure you apply as much is not needed to spring the tray.