# How can I avoid losing or missing a SIM ejector tool?

Tags: substitute-tool

A SIM ejector tool is very tiny, and it is difficult to keep it safe from losing it or missing it anywhere. How can I keep it safe?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/10582/6973

Comment: @Chenmunka not a dupe, imho, but will come handy if (when?) the  (not yet) suggested methods fail ;-)

Comment: Hi Hemlata, Welcome to Lifehacks. Please visit the [Tour] and [Help] to get ideas how best to use this site.

Comment: I do not see where a lifehack is involved as this question stands. There are myriad storage solutions for a small object such as this. More appropriate is the suggestion by @Chenmunka in comment.

Comment: The one that came with my phone was designed to attach to a keychain.

Comment: If you lose it, use a paperclip

Comment: you just need a girlfriend that always wears pin type ear-rings, then you have access to the right tool when you need it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done is keep **SIM ejector tool** in **small plastic container** I already have.
And keep it **in another one** where I keep **my USB flash drives**.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Keep it in the box in the same housing where it was supplied, along with the mini-manual you get, and the receipt.

If you didn't keep the box, put in a small plastic bag (like a coin bag) inside a larger envelope that is not so easy to lose.

Or use masking tape to fix it to piece of card, and put that in an envelope.

Write on the envelope what it contains.

---

Or – **hack** – use an opened paper clip instead, if you need to remove the SIM.

In both cases, insert the tool carefully at right-angles – not at a slope – so you don't damage any internal component.

**Edit**: in reply to those who say a paper clip does not work, the first paper clip I tried is exactly the diameter of the supplied tool, and successfully ejects the SIM cradle. YMMV.

Comment: Or sellotape it to the wall

Comment: Paper clips are usually too thick. I prefer using a small safety pin.

Comment: I would sellotape it to the backside of the smartphone .. or if you use one .. put it in the protective casing for your phone "under" your phone .. solved

Comment: @eagle275 thanks but there is already an [answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/23374/28188) for that.

Comment: guessed as much - hence I wrote only as comment

Comment: paper clip doesnt work. tried it last week. Doesnt give enough pressure without bending

Comment: @vikingsteve thanks, I have edited the answer.

Comment: One of the main reasons I *always* keep the box, along with having the box in the case of re-sale later. Samsung Notes come with replacement nibs for the stylus, along with the SIM tool. The box is by far the most logical place to store small pieces like that if I want to be able to find them later.

Comment: @Carcigenicate me too: there can be contact information, serial numbers, model version, etc which are not present on the phone. Someone I know installed Windows and threw away all the packaging, and then was asked for a unique code to activate it that was on the packaging.

Comment: I had a paperclip that was too thick. The paperclip was made of metal coated in plastic. I removed the plastic coating from one end and now it fits perfectly.

Comment: Project Fi actually used to ship a paperclip with SIM cards, instead of a custom SIM ejector. (It was helpfully clipped onto the setup sheet.)

Answer (score 12):

If it has a small hole on its rear end, put it on your keyring. Some designs don't have this, some do.

Comment: Keyrings are usually carried (by me) in pants pockets. Those little buggers poke through the fabric and into the skin to make for really uncomfortable sensations. - Not a good idea, at all!

Answer (score 8):

If you are using case for your phone - consider dropping it inside when you put the case on.

Answer (score 4):

I keep it in my wallet, with the coins. Not only it doesn't get lost, it's also always available when I suddenly unexpectedly need it. This may even be a lifehack, because it wasn't meant to be kept in a wallet.

Answer (score 2):

Disassemble an old speaker if you can find one, and take the magnet off the tweeter or woofer. Find a nice metal place to stick it to on your desk, then have the magnet keep a hold of the sim ejector.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about losing it; plenty of every day objects can be used as a sim ejector:

- a safety or sewing pin
- staple (opened)
- paperclip
- drawing pin
- an earring (pin, not clip on type)
- a fine drill bit

If you're really desperate, filing a hair clip down with a nail file etc.. I've had to resort to stripping the wire out of a freezer bag tie and tripling it up/twisting it really tightly before now. It should also be noted that your chosen object will need to fit in the hole *and be slightly loose* especially if the hole is in the moving part of the door because as you push the tool in, the door will want to slide in the opposite direction; a tight fit will inhibit this and could result in breaking the tool

Most sim ejector tools I've come across are approximately shaped like a sports racket; the hoop section could thus attach to something you typically bring along, like your keys or headphones wire (form a loop in the wire, push it through the racket then back over itself around the outside of the racket, perhaps even the zip pull of your jacket. If you have a shock proof case for your phone it should also easily sit between the case and the phone

Answer (score 1):

Keep it taped to the back of your ID (or another card that you always have with you that doesn't have to be tapped/swiped). This way it will always be in your wallet/purse.

Bonus tip: If you have two sim cards (because maybe you do business in multiple countries), keep your other sim taped like this as well. You'll always have them when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I keep it in my wallet - either in the coin purse, or in the cards section. This allows me access to it when I am on the go as well.

Comment: Yes I can have it in wallet which has slot for SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a somewhat tight phone case, (otterbox for example) try keeping your sim ejector inside your case, so it is always in your hands when you need it, just take off the case and you're good

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Answer (score 0):

I tape mine to my desk because that's usually where I'm at when I find myself in need of it. It's too small to put in a desk drawer, however, it could be taped to the inside of a drawer.